# A function that takes email address and booked hrs as input and returns the remaining hrs from a dictionary

Tags: python, database

I am trying to write a python code that takes `email` and `booking` as my input and returns the remaining hours by subtracting the value in `db` by `booking`. The `db` is a dictionary that maps the `email` to a number which is essentially the hours that are left after each booking and I would like the `db.value` to be updated after each booking. What is the easiest way to do this?

here is my code so far:

```
def prepaidhrs(email, booking, db):

    if email in db.keys:

        db.value -= booking

    return db.value

db={'12345678@gmail.com':60}
```

Comment: Don't describe your code, but share it here - try solving the problem yourself and ask questions about the solution if it doesn't work, or make it very clear what is the part you're not sure how to solve. (and by the way, naming that dictionary `cache` will be confusing to most programmers, because that's not what a cache is)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a booking method , it will take the email and booking hours as input , then it will parse your dictionnary , and get the number of hours left and substract the booking from it

```
 def booking(email,booking) :
     for element in dictionnary : 
         if(element.key == email) :
            return element.value - booking
```

Next step is to update your dictionnary , here it may not be possible because some of Python objects arre immutable , so you'll maybe find yourself forced to create a new dictionnary with an updated value